# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

Как исправить данную ошибку сборки и импортировать ExoPlayer в проект Android Studio?

Получаю ошибку сборки в своем учебном проекте под Android. Чистый проект сразу после создания успешно собирается, но невозможно собрать проект с импортированным ExoPlayer - gradle sync успешно выполняется, но при попытке собрать проект получаю множественные ошибки сборки вида:

```
> Failed to transform exoplayer-common-2.18.6.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.18.6) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
          > Could not find exoplayer-common-2.18.6.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.18.6).
            Searched in the following locations:
                https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-common/2.18.6/exoplayer-common-2.18.6.aar
```

При попытке открыть в браузере приводимые в ошибках ссылки, сервер возвращает 404.
В старых ответах на аналогичные вопросы говорят, что необходимо использовать свежие версии библиотек, но я и так использую последние версии, соответственно те ответы мне не помогли.

> build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'org.example.exoplayeractivity'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.example.exoplayeractivity"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

> setting.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "exoPlayerActivity"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с Exoplayer Google рекомендует воспользоваться такими зависимостями:

```
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.0.1"
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.0.1"
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.0.1"
```

и дальше плеер создается таким образом:

```
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
```

[Вот есть пример](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/hello-world) от Google как добавить и использовать данный функционал у себя в проекте.

### UPDATE

Вот конфиг свежего проекта который я попробовал создать:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.cleverapptech.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cleverapptech.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

def mediaVersion = "1.0.1"
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:$mediaVersion"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:$mediaVersion"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:$mediaVersion"
}
```

и:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: Выдает ту же самую ошибку, но уже с этими зависимостями.

Comment: а это вам зачем - `repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)` ? оно для чего используется?

Comment: это я пытался копипастить со старых ответов. Удалил эту строку и выполнил обновление конфигурации, но это ни на что не повлияло - ошибки при сборке остались те же.

Comment: а если свежий проект сделать? и с этими зависимостями тоже будет ошибка? вот есть примерчик прям гугловый как сделать приложение - https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#0

Comment: Да, на новом проекте та же ошибка. Только созданный проект собирается, а после импортирования зависимостей - уже нет.

Comment: удалите папку .gradle, я вот только что попробовал на чистом проекте, добавил зависимости, собралось и запустилось неоднократно, допускаю что в градле просто сейчас ошибка висит и все

Comment: @NikMAX, обновил ответ

Comment: Обновил Android Studio, удалил .gradle, перекачал заново - безрезультатно. Новосозданный проект собирается успешно. Добавляю зависимость exoplayer - выдает две ошибки загрузки: `Failed https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer/2.18.5/exoplayer-2.18.5.pom 145 ms 0 B 0 B/s` и `Failed https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer/2.18.5/exoplayer-2.18.5.pom 210 ms 0 B 0 B/s`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145675/discussion-between-andrew-and-nikmax).

Answer (score 0):

Перебирая случайные варианты я нашел решение.
Перед тем как задать вопрос я пытался добавить зависимость в модуль:

`Project structure -> Dependencies -> app`

А нужно було добавлять зависимость во все модули:

`Project structure -> Dependencies -> <All Modules>`

Файлы `build.gradle` выглядят так же, как и когда я добавлял зависимость только в один модуль, но теперь проект с новой зависимостью успешно собирается. Не понимаю почему, но работает.

Большое спасибо [Andrew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/238742/andrew) за то, что уделил время и направил в нужном направлении.